# how to check if a given URL is HTTP or HTTPS in C#

Tags: c#, url, https

I need to check if a given URL (which is not necessarily prefixed with http or https) is HTTP or HTTPs.
Is this possible in C#?
If the user gives just www.dotnetperls.com without any prefix, I must be able to identify that it is an HTTP one. Tried the following,

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.dotnetpearls.com");         
 string u = request.RequestUri.Scheme;
```

But this gives an Invalid URL error. It expects the protocol to be specified.

Comment: your question does not make sense. if an url does not have https it is http

Comment: But in my case, the user may enter any url say, www.wikipedia.org, which is actually an HTTPS. So in this case I need to find if its is an HTTPS or HTTP and display a warning message accordingly only if HTTP.

Comment: you have to use webclient and make a request to http and check if it is http or https with Request.IsSecureConnection

Comment: Can you provide an example URL that doesn't contain the protocol?

Comment: But it doesn't let me give a URL without protocol.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example

Comment: web requests are BY DEFAULT http. The client can NOT simply ignore that and start firing off https requests. Not all sites are https-enabled. The initial request, if you don't explicitly specify https in the url, HAS to be http, and then the remote server can issue a redirect and point you at the https version instead. But regardless, your initial protocol-less-url hit HAS to be http. HTTP 2.0 will apparently change to an ssl-first-by-default mode, but that's at some vague point in the future, not "today".

Answer (score 13):

try something like this:

```
public static bool IsHttps()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;
}
```

Or if you working with [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) you can check if [`Request.RequestUri.Scheme`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api) is `Uri.UriSchemeHttps`.

Comment: but I all I have is just a url without http/https prefix and not a http request itself.

Answer (score 10):

```
var uri = new Uri("https://sss.com");
var requestType= uri.Scheme;
```

Here the `requestType` will will give you whether the request is of type `http` or `https`

Comment: My url does not contain a http/https prefix. So cant use this, since it will show "URI not in correct format error".

Answer (score 2):

```
if (url.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a solution for the same as well and unfortunately I couldn't find any.

And also some websites doesn't support www as well.

So I'm sending 4 requests to find out if the website supports https and finding the one that supports.

I know this is not a good solution but it works at least.
If the first one works, I'm not calling the rest of them...

1. WebRequest.Create("http**s**://dotnetpearls.com");
2. WebRequest.Create("http**s**://**www**.dotnetpearls.com");
3. WebRequest.Create("http://dotnetpearls.com");
4. WebRequest.Create("http://www.dotnetpearls.com");

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

OR, where request object is available.

```
Request.IsSecureConnection
```

Comment: but I all I have is just a url without http/https prefix and not a http request itself.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.net core the property Request.Scheme is available that works for me:

```
var uri = String.Format("{0}://{1}",Request.Scheme,Request.Host.Value);
```