# Getting the root URL of a function app host in C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Basically I have a function app and I want it to be able to call itself via HttpTrigger for reasons.  (The reasons are to send messages to SignalR by calling `/api/message` and that is how the last programmer did it.) However, I would like to not have to explicitly set the root via local.settings.json or configuration settings on the portal. Best I have so far is

```cs
        builder.Services.AddHttpClient("FunctionSelfReference", s =>
        {
            s.BaseAddress = new Uri($"http://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")}");
        });
```

I'm not even sure if that will be set on a serverless function app instance, and I have not found an environment variable that can tell me if its http or https (but I guess that't just a matter of it being local or not).

In the service container I have the following available to me:

```
AzureComponentFactory - Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.AzureComponentFactory
AzureEventSourceLogForwarder - Microsoft.Extensions.Azure.AzureEventSourceLogForwarder
Cache - Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1+Cache
CompositeBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.CompositeBindingProvider
CompositeBindingProviderFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.CompositeBindingProviderFactory
ConcurrencyManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ConcurrencyManager
DefaultHttpClientFactory - Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory
DefaultTriggerBindingFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.DefaultTriggerBindingFactory
ExternalConfigurationStartupValidator - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.DependencyInjection.ExternalConfigurationStartupValidator
FunctionExecutor - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor
HostBuilderContext - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilderContext
HttpClient - System.Net.Http.HttpClient
HttpClientMappingRegistry - Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientMappingRegistry
HttpMessageHandlerBuilder - Microsoft.Extensions.Http.HttpMessageHandlerBuilder
IApplicationLifetime - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IApplicationLifetime
IApplicationLifetimeWrapper - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IApplicationLifetimeWrapper
IAsyncCollector`1 - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IAsyncCollector`1[[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.FunctionInstanceLogEntry, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.36.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.IBindingProvider
IConcurrencyStatusRepository - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IConcurrencyStatusRepository
IConcurrencyThrottleManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IConcurrencyThrottleManager
IConcurrencyThrottleProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IConcurrencyThrottleProvider
IConcurrencyThrottleProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IConcurrencyThrottleProvider
IConfiguration - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration
IConnectionInfoResolver - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IConnectionInfoResolver
IConnectionStringResolver - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IConnectionStringResolver
IContentNegotiator - System.Net.Http.Formatting.IContentNegotiator
IContextGetter`1 - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.IContextGetter`1[[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.IMessageEnqueuedWatcher, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues, Version=5.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8]]
IContextSetter`1 - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.IContextSetter`1[[Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.IMessageEnqueuedWatcher, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues, Version=5.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8]]
IConverterManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IConverterManager
IDashboardLoggingSetup - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IDashboardLoggingSetup
IDistributedLockManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IDistributedLockManager
IDrainModeManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IDrainModeManager
IDurabilityProviderFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IDurabilityProviderFactory
IDurableClientFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.ContextImplementations.IDurableClientFactory
IDurableHttpMessageHandlerFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IDurableHttpMessageHandlerFactory
IErrorSerializerSettingsFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IErrorSerializerSettingsFactory
IEventCollectorFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.IEventCollectorFactory
IEventCollectorProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.IEventCollectorProvider
IExtensionBundleManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionBundle.IExtensionBundleManager
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionConfigProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionConfigProvider
IExtensionOptionsProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionOptionsProvider
IExtensionOptionsProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionOptionsProvider
IExtensionOptionsProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionOptionsProvider
IExtensionOptionsProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Config.IExtensionOptionsProvider
IExtensionRegistry - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IExtensionRegistry
IExtensionRegistryFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IExtensionRegistryFactory
IFileWriterFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileWriterFactory
IFunctionActivityStatusProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IFunctionActivityStatusProvider
IFunctionExecutor - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IFunctionExecutor
IFunctionIndexProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.IFunctionIndexProvider
IFunctionInstanceLogger - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.IFunctionInstanceLogger
IFunctionOutputLogger - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.IFunctionOutputLogger
IHost - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHost
IHostApplicationLifetime - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime
IHostedService - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
IHostedService - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
IHostedService - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
IHostedService - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
IHostedService - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService
IHostEnvironment - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment
IHostIdProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IHostIdProvider
IHostingEnvironment - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment
IHostInstanceLogger - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Loggers.IHostInstanceLogger
IHostLifetime - Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostLifetime
IHostProcessMonitor - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IHostProcessMonitor
IHostSingletonManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IHostSingletonManager
IHttpClientFactory - System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory
IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter - Microsoft.Extensions.Http.IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter
IHttpMessageHandlerFactory - System.Net.Http.IHttpMessageHandlerFactory
IJobActivator - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IJobActivator
IJobHost - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IJobHost
IJobHostContextFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.IJobHostContextFactory
IJobHostMetadataProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IJobHostMetadataProvider
IJobHostMetadataProviderFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.IJobHostMetadataProviderFactory
ILoadBalancerQueue - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ILoadBalancerQueue
ILogger`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1
ILoggerFactory - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory
ILoggerProvider - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider
ILoggerProvider - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerProvider
ILoggerProviderConfiguration`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.ILoggerProviderConfiguration`1
ILoggerProviderConfigurationFactory - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.ILoggerProviderConfigurationFactory
IMessageSerializerSettingsFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IMessageSerializerSettingsFactory
INameResolver - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.INameResolver
IOptions`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1
IOptionsChangeTokenSource`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsChangeTokenSource`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterOptions, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]
IOptionsFactory`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsFactory`1
IOptionsFactory`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsFactory`1
IOptionsFormatter`1 - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IOptionsFormatter`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterOptions, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]]
IOptionsLoggingSource - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IOptionsLoggingSource
IOptionsMonitor`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitor`1
IOptionsMonitorCache`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsMonitorCache`1
IOptionsSnapshot`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptionsSnapshot`1
IPlatformInformation - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IPlatformInformation
IPrimaryHostStateProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IPrimaryHostStateProvider
IQueueProcessorFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.IQueueProcessorFactory
IScaleMonitorManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.IScaleMonitorManager
IServiceManagerStore - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService.IServiceManagerStore
ISharedContextProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ISharedContextProvider
ISharedContextProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.ISharedContextProvider
IStorageAccountProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.IStorageAccountProvider
ITargetScalerManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Scale.ITargetScalerManager
ITelemetryActivator - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Correlation.ITelemetryActivator
ITokenCredentialFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Auth.ITokenCredentialFactory
ITriggerBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Triggers.ITriggerBindingProvider
ITypedHttpClientFactory`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ITypedHttpClientFactory`1
ITypeLocator - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ITypeLocator
IWebJobsExceptionHandler - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.IWebJobsExceptionHandler
IWebJobsExceptionHandlerFactory - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.IWebJobsExceptionHandlerFactory
IWebJobsExtensionConfiguration`1 - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Configuration.IWebJobsExtensionConfiguration`1
LoggingConfiguration - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.LoggingConfiguration
OptionsFactory`1 - Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1
QueueCausalityManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues.QueueCausalityManager
QueueServiceClientProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues.QueueServiceClientProvider
QueueTriggerAttributeBindingProvider - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues.Triggers.QueueTriggerAttributeBindingProvider
ScheduleMonitor - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.ScheduleMonitor
ScheduleMonitor - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.ScheduleMonitor
SharedQueueHandler - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Dispatch.SharedQueueHandler
SharedQueueWatcher - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Common.Listeners.SharedQueueWatcher
SingletonManager - Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.SingletonManager
```

Comment: Maybe use `localhost`?

Comment: So, the function is an http triggered function, and when triggered it needs to call itself?

Answer (score 0):

We can see the `Environment Variable` in `KUDU` Console.

[image]

> I'm not even sure if that will be set on a serverless function app instance

Yes,It is possible to set in Function App.

- I have used the same `Environment Variable` which you have mentioned,
  `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")` in the Function.

```cs
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var hosturl = new Uri($"http://{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")}");
            log.LogInformation("Host URL is " + hosturl);

            ....
```

***Local Output:***
[image]

***Deployed Function App Output:***

[image]

[image]

Thanks @[Thomas Ardal](https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-get-base-url-in-asp-net-core/) for the code.

We can also use `HttpRequest` to get the Hostname.

```cs
 var reqs = req.HttpContext.Request;
 var Url = $"{reqs.Scheme}://{reqs.Host.Value}";
 log.LogInformation($"Root URL: {Url}");
```

***OR***

```cs
var url = String.Format("{0}://{1}", reqs.Scheme, reqs.Host.Value);
```

> I have not found an environment variable that can tell me if its http or https

Refer [how to check if a given URL is HTTP or HTTPS in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20679016/) for more details.